# Is there a way to specify which browser heroku uses with `heroku open`?

Tags: heroku-toolbelt

In a folder with a heroku application running `heroku open` or `heroku apps:open` will open the page with firefox. My default browser is google-chrome and running:

```
xdg-open http://www.google.com
```

opens this. Is there a way to set heroku to open the correct default browser? (I could not find any useful help on the internet or through `heroku help open`)

Comment: I too would like to know this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worked for me only after i've added BROWSER environment variable:

`$ export BROWSER=chromium-browser`

However, in Windows it might be another way to do that.

Comment: Right you are, just saw this. [Here is a page](https://www.airpair.com/heroku/posts/heroku-tips-and-hacks#2-3-open) that outlines that and other heroku tips.